# Angular - WhatsApp share href hashtag is cutting text

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app, I have a WhatsApp share button which contains the URL to my site:

```
$scope.whatsappHRef = 'whatsapp://send?text=https://www.example.com/#' + $location.path();
```

However when I click on this the URL is not being displayed after the `#`, so I just get `https://www.example.com`.

I've removed the `#` and `location.path()` displays fine, so its def. the hashtag causing the block.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Enable Html5Mode for your app.  However, be aware that this may require changing the configuration on your server as well as within your app.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#!/

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that if possible.